# How to move folder between git branches?

Tags: git

I have a directory contening two folders `src` and `build`. That directory is in under git control (branch `master`).

What I want to do is to move the content of the `build` folder at the root of the branch `gh-pages` .

I can do it manually with a lot of commands but I'm sure that it can be done in an easy way.

Comment: It sounds like you want [this](https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

To push directories to a branch, you can use:

```
git subtree push --prefix dir origin branch
```

See [this guide](https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490) on deploying to gh-pages.

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout master
mv build tmp-build
git rm -rf build
git commit . -m "moving build to gh-pages"
git checkout -b gh-pages
mv tmp-build build
git add build
git commit . -m "moved build from master"
```

Sorry, it's as terse as I can get it.